# Warframe keeps crashing my computer

Tags: warframe

As of Update 14, I've had consistent computer crashes. If I am ever in a Void or Derelict mission, something like an ability can cause a crash, my graphics are as low as they go and II have nothing else running. Is there any advice to prevent these? These crashes usually occurs when I use an ability or too many enemies are on the screen at a given time. I have had occasions where other players abilities have crashed my computer. Before Update 14 This would happen In Vault missions mainly, but it has spread to Void missions as of U 14. This crash issue has been infuriating with argon crystal farming as they only stay in your inventory until the next day reset.

Comment: Hello Dav, and welcome to Gaming StackExchange. Do you know if you can give us some more info on what is going wrong exactly? You can use the edit button to edit the post you created (duh) to add more info about the problems.

Comment: Those symptoms sound a bit like your computer overheating.  How old is it?  Can you monitor the CPU and GPU temperatures?  If so, how high does it get when it shuts down?

Comment: The computer is half a year old, and I would need to learn how to moniter that infermation